# Can USB have two bootable OS'es

Tags: boot, usb

**Motivation**

I often need to reinstall different operating systems on different computers. Instead of having to download the OS from the NET each time, I would like to save it on the USB. Then I could plug the USB stick into PC, boot from USB (with the help of BIOS settings), and install the OS. It would also help me to quickly reinstall my own OS, if something gets corrupted (that has already happened to me).

At boot time I want to have an option of selecting which OS to load from USB, just as I have an option of selecting which OS to load from disc.

The reason why I want to have everything in one place is because I have a nice tiny USB stick, which has 32 GB of storage, and which can be easily carried in my wallet.

**What's done so far**

I succeeded installing a single OS into `Kingston Data Traveler 32GB` USB stick.
After changing the boot order in BIOS settings, everything works.

Now I want to try install multiple OSes using another Windows program called YUMI.

My BIOS boot order is: `USB FDD`, `USB HDD`, `USB CDROM`, `HDD1`, `Ubuntu`, `Windows`, [rest]. When I use YUMI to make a multi OS USB and try to install the same OS as before (just one OS so far but using YUMI program now), the problem occurs. The BIOS no longer recognizes that the USB stick contains OS, and therefore prevents from booting into it. What happens is that the standard boot menu appears with Linux and Windows available, and nothing more, just as it would appear without any USB stick connected.

One of the 2 possible reasons I believe this could happen is:

1. `Kingston Data Traveler` USB does not have an option to contain multiple OSes.
2. The OS is stored in the USB using the wrong format: some path to the OS directory is missing, or whatever.

**Questions**

Is it possible to have multiple OS'es on Kingston Data Traveler? Do you think the problem could be one of the 2 above? How to solve it?

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-multiple-bootable-operating-systems-on-one-usb-stick/  this may help you get started

Comment: You seem to be right. Should I delete the post then?

Answer (score 2):

YUMI or SARDU
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/tag/multiboot-usb/

I've used YUMI quite a bit. It is meant mostly as a multi live Linux USB creator. Works most of the time with installs if you need to.

Comment: I used YUMI to add one OS to the USB. The USB stick now has a directory multiboot. It inside contains a bunch of files, an empty ISOS directory, and ubuntu-14.02 directory. The ubuntu-14.02 directory is the place where the actual OS is installed (I believe).

My question now is: how to make this USB bootable? After I restart PC, it doesn't boot from USB, even if BIOS settings are correctly set. Do I need to add some shortcut to ISOS folder, or do something else? I believe there is still one step to be done that I am missing.

Comment: (My USB stick is [Kingston Data Traveler 32GB](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Kingston-DataTraveler-Micro-3-1-32GB-USB-3-1-Flash-Stick-Pen-Memory-Drive-/181775298099?hash=item2a52a6ee33:g:WDoAAOSwHnFVjiEM))

Comment: YUMI it should have made the USB bootable for you. Sometimes bootables don't work in a USB3.0 slot. Find out what button brings you to your bootable menu (F2, F9 and Esc are common) then make sure that you see your stick then select it. YUMI will boot up to a screen then select your os from there. With YUMI you can add/delete ISOs as you please.

Answer (score 1):

I think yes though I don't think it's currently easy or well managed. *I also have not tested this method at all.*

Theoretically if you had a USB stick that was large enough for both Windows and Linux (probably 8-16GB to be safe) you could put the Windows and Linux Installers on it (make sure to format it to Fat32).

Start by putting Windows on it with [MS's USB tool](https://wudt.codeplex.com/). After that's done, resize the partition on the USB down to just the size of the Windows installer data and format the other half of the USB stick to a different Fat32 partition.

Then use something like [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to install Linux to the other partition being careful **not** to select format partition/drive but be sure to **enable persistence** with as much room as is left on the stick.

After that's done, try booting Linux live installer into a live environment. You'll want to install grub if it's not on the stick already.

If it's a Debian OS, I'd recommend using https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer to manage grub configuration as it makes it quite easy.

```
This PPA contains the latest release of Grub Customizer.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Verify Windows is seen before writing the bootloader to the USB stick and you should be good to go.

If the Windows Installer doesn't get detected automatically, you ought to be able to manually add an entry that points to it's specific location i.e. something like `/dev/sdb2`.